# Indentation of hard coded long list

Tags: haskell, indentation

## Background

I have a long hard coded list. I wish to have it spanned across several lines.

```hs
let partition = [1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30,42,56,77,101,135,176,231,
                 297,385,490,627,792,1002,1255,1575,1958,2436,3010,
                 3718,4565,5604,6842,8349,10143,12310,14883,17977,
                 21637,26015,31185,37338,44583,53174,63261,75175,
                 89134,105558,124754,147273,173525]
```

## Problem

No matter what indentation I try, the error persisted.

`parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Comment: If this is in a source file at the top level, get rid of the `let`. That's only for ghci and local bindings.

Comment: This is working great here. (In GHCI be sure to set multi-line) `:set +m`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Haskell and working in a source file. I have get rid of the `let` as suggested by @luqui. The error is somehow misleading. LOL

Comment: @Gavin, yeah that one misleads people often.  That's just the message for syntax error, reminding you that indentation is part of the syntax in Haskell.  ``foo) =# 4tr` $ $`` would give the same error

Comment: I usually use the indentation style on lines 42-45 of https://github.com/quickdudley/varroa/blob/33b7c51992b590dc4e11a53164a4a0eb1d31f5fb/study.hs for multi-line lists.